# How to fix error from Android change icons in resources direcotry: "Aapt2Compile" task returned false but did not log an error

Tags: c#, xamarin

I just change the icon.png with icon with the same name in the directories:

```
mipmap-hdpi
mipmap-mdpi
mipmap-xhdpi
mipmap-xxhdpi
mipmap-xxxhdpi
```

on my android project, but when I want to archieve I receive this error message:

```
/Users/pizhev/Projects/New App/WeatherLocationInfo 0.0.6 Android/WeatherLocationInfo.Android/Resources/mipmap-mdpi/icon.png(3,3): Warning: The "Aapt2Compile" task returned false but did not log an error. (WeatherLocationInfo)
```

When I click on the error he open the icon.png

Other errors is: `/Users/pizhev/Projects/New App/WeatherLocationInfo 0.0.6 Android/WeatherLocationInfo.Android/Resources/mipmap-xhdpi/icon.png: Warning: file not found. (WeatherLocationInfo)`

And again when I click on this error He open the icon ?

Is there a way to fix this errors ?

Comment: Did you try to delete bin and obj files,then rebuild your project ?

Comment: I delete obj and bin folders on global project and android project but error is the same...

Comment: You could try adding back the file type suffix `. png`.